# Trying to create n*m matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to create

board(2, 3)

which results in

[[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]

However I'm just getting 6 `None`s in a row and not a break between the two groups.

```
def none_board(n, m):
    a = []
    a += [None]*m 
    b = []
    b += [a*n]
    return b
```

Comment: Why are you erasing your code? Code is good for a question, "a series of a certain word regarding theorizing abstractness" is not helpful.

Comment: @Leonardo wrong code of not problem

Comment: @user3555502: Someone has already provided an answer to the question you asked. If you want to ask a new question, start a new question, don't edit this one beyond all recognition.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, this is done:

```
def none_board(n, m):
    return [[None for _ in range(m)] 
            for _ in range(n)]
```

The code

```
l1 += l2
```

Is equivalent to

```
l1.extend(l2)
```

Not

```
l1.append(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jonrsharpe's answer, I'd like to say, don't use `*` operator to create a multi-dimensional list. When you write `a = [None] * 3`, it's perfectly okay and creates a list of 3 `None`s. But when you write `b = [a] * 2`, it will indeed be a 2x3 list, but the 2 rows would refer to the same memory location, because `a` is a reference, and it will be copied in each row.

For example:

```
>>> a = [None] * 3
>>> print a
[None, None, None]
>>> b = [a] * 2
>>> print b
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
>>> a[0] = 0
>>> print a
[0, None, None]
>>> print b
[[0, None, None], [0, None, None]]
>>> b[0][1] = 1
>>> print b
[[0, 1, None], [0, 1, None]]
```

So `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]` refer to the same location, and changing a value in `a` would change `b` at multiple places, which is unexpected.

Use `*` operator to create a list only when the items of the list are of primitive types.